# how to use vue search select in multiple form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to show select option of my product in multiple form. But the problem is, when i choose one option in one of my form, the other select forms also changes.

what i have to do, to make it unique?

here what i try

my select form

```
<tr v-for="(adddiagnosilom, index) in adddiagnosis" :key="adddiagnosilom.value">
    <td>{{ adddiagnosilom.value }}</td>
    <td>{{ adddiagnosilom.CodeID }}</td>
    <td>{{ adddiagnosilom.text }}</td>
    <td>
        <ListSelect :list="optionProduct"
             option-value="value"
             option-text="text"
             :selected-item="itemproduct[index]"
             placeholder="select product"
             @select="onSelectProduct">
        </ListSelect>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="0" v-model="adddiagnosilom.ordered">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="0" v-model="adddiagnosilom.price">
    </td>
    <td>{{ adddiagnosilom.sum = adddiagnosilom.ordered * adddiagnosilom.price }}</td>
</tr>
```

my variable

```
data() {
    return {
      adddiagnosis: {},
      itemproduct: [
        { value: '', text: '' }
     ],
    }
}
```

my select method

```
onSelectProduct (itemproduct) {
    this.itemproduct = itemproduct
},
```

here is the screenshot
[image]

all select option will change when one of it i change. what i want to do is only change the select form that i change, not all of it.

Comment: Create ListSelect as a different component and render the component at the place.So that every select would have its own variable.

Comment: Because you are binding the same `itemproduct` object to each `ListSelect`. You need to have an array of `itemproduct`

Comment: @adiga yup, thats it. but i dont know how to make it as an array.

Comment: your index is not functioning then, start your debug from there

Answer (score 0):

Make `itemproduct` an array and then bind to `itemproduct[index]` instead of `itemproduct`. Then you'll have an array with the value of each select box as a separate index.

Comment: im edit my answer based on what u say, please review it again, and i got error like this `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "selectedItem". Expected Object, got Array.`

Comment: Should be like this data() {
    return {
      adddiagnosis: {},
      itemproduct: [
     ],
    }
}

Comment: Relace your 2nd line with this -> <td v-if="1 ? itemproduct[index] = {} : 0">{{ adddiagnosilom.value }}</td>